# Merge two excel sheets when UserId match in both sheets

Tags: excel

I am currently mapping the usage of an application. The app have more than 5000 users and each of those users have different prerogatives. Because this an application used by employees of a company the only way I can segment those users is by using their coresponding service.

I have two seperate excel sheets that look like this:

1/

```
UserId    N°connection/month
1         34
2         21
3         3
4         67
5         2
```

2/

```
UserId    Name    Service associated
2         Peter   Department 1
5         Lily    Department 2
3         Sarah   Department 3
1         Gary    Department 1
4         Joe     Department 4
```

What I would like is to join those two separate excel sheets. Excel needs to merge those different informations by UserId.

So what I am looking for looks like this:

```
UserId    N°connection/month    Name    Service associated
1         34                    Gary    Department 1
2         21                    Peter   Department 1
3         3                     Sarah   Department 3
```

It is important to know that the two excel sheets have a different number of rows. 
Does anyone have a solution ? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`VLOOKUP` will work, but I would suggest `INDEX` and `MATCH` be used together - it is faster and is less fragile than VLOOKUP. It also doesn't require the UserID to be at the beginning of the row. A quick search will yield a result.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I got your question. But if I did, this should be pretty easy to do using VLOOKUP formula on the merged sheet.

This link might help: https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/vlookup.php